# tinyMCE \r\n as new line breaker

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

In my app i'm use tinyMCE editor to create rich email content, but now I need also sent messages as plain text now. Did someone knew how to force tinyMCE to use as a simple text editor w o any content editing, and use `\r\n` as line breaker?

I'm really stack at this moment, and thinking about writing own simple text editor, based on textarea. Didn't find in tinyMCE docs any solution.

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE is an HTML editor - there is no option to turn it into a plain text editor.  The best you could do with TinyMCE is to transform the HTML into plain text when saving the form.